# Is it possible to have two different URI's in the same @Path using regex for my Rest?

Tags: java, rest

I'd like to know if it's possible to have two different URI's in the same (Rest) @Path using regex or something else.

Eg.:

```
@Path("{path: (/foo1|/foo2)}")
public class Service {
    ...
}
```

Or something like that.

I'd like to call something like:

```
http://localhost/foo1
http://localhost/foo2
```

But using the same class.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably (I didn't try it myself).  [From The RESTful Web Services Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/index.html) (this is not your specific case...the regex is left as an exercise for the reader):

> If it is required that a user name must only consist of lower and upper case numeric characters, it is possible to declare a particular regular expression that will override the default regular expression, `[^/]+?`. The following example shows how this could be used with the `@Path` annotation.

```
@Path("users/{username: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]}")
```

This example is from [The @Path Annotation and URI Path Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqny/index.html) in the guide referenced above.